# How do I solve $(a+x)e^{-bx} = c$?

Tags: exponential-function, lambert-w

How do I solve $$(a+x)\mathrm e^{-bx} = c?$$ I tried looking into Lambert W function but was not able to solve it.

Comment: Note that $z=-b(x+a)$ solves $ze^z=-bce^{-ba}$ and apply the definition of Lambert W (for no gain except a useless pseudo-explicit formula...).

Answer (score 1):

It's not difficult to express the solution with the W function

$$(a+x)e^{-bx} = c \Leftrightarrow (-ba-bx)e^{-bx} = -bc$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow (-ba-bx)e^{-ba-bx} = -bce^{-ba}$$

So we have $-ba-bx = W( -bce^{-ba} )$

Hence

$$x = -a-\frac{W( -bce^{-ba} )}{b}$$